Считать значение по умолчанию в input file
Друзья, буду признателен за помощь в решении следующей проблемы:
есть у меня input type='file' с заданным значением value='./story/game/game.txt':
<input type="file" id="file2" value="./story/game/game.txt">

так же я навоял некоторую функцию, которая по идее должна считывать данные из файла по указанному пути:
function AutoReadFile() {
  let file = document.getElementById('file2').files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.readAsText(file)
  reader.onload = function () {
    console.log(reader.result)
  }
  reader.onerror = function () {
    console.log(reader.error)
  }
}


данная функция может выполняться как без участия пользователя, так и привязываться к нажатию кнопки... Однако моя задумка явно не работает... Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как сие счатье заставить работать?
В идеале я хочу сделать так, чтобы система сначала проверяла наличие данного файла и, если он есть, считывала из него данные, а если его нет, то предлагала выбрать необходимый файл.
Я знаю множество решений через addEventListener, однако все они предполагают отслеживание каких-либо изменений в инпуте, а вот как считать значение по умолчанию без дополнительных действий, вопрос?

Чтение файлов без участия пользователя запрещено. Допустить такое значит допустить утечку информации пользователя. Вы не можете никак читать какой-либо файл пока пользователь сам его не загрузит.

File System API

@Qwertiy, правильно подозреваешь... Я делаю локальное ХТМД приложение, где главная задумка заключается в том, чтобы все это работало без участия интернета и серверов.

@drakoblack, там надо сервер локально поднять - и всё. Ну или раскладывай всё в js-файлы (хотя, вообще-то, я не проверил, что их можно подключать динамически).

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
